# Getting the old selected index in Winform's Combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box (winform). This combo box has some items (eg. 1,2,3,4).

Now, when I change the selection within this combo, I wish to know the **old index** and the **new index**.

How do I get this?

Possible approaches that I wish to **AVOID**.

1. Add an **enter event**, cache the current index and then on selection index change get the new index.
2. Using the selected text/selected item property received by the sender of the event.

**What I ideally want:**

1. In the event args that are received, I want something like:

   e.OldIndex;
   e.newIndex;

   Right now the event args which are received in the **SelectionIndex Change event** are totally useless.
2. I don't want to use more than one event.
3. If C#, does not offer this, can I have my event which passes the old index and new index as event args?

Comment: Hi Nikhil, you can do it using one variable and without any events, if you agree the idea tell me to Post the code as an answer.

Comment: ComboBoxEdit by devexpress has EditValueChanging event.if you don't want to do anything with index and just want text property then it is better control than standard combobox. See http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_EditValueChangingtopic

Comment: possible duplicate of [ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged event: how to get the previously selected index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237885/combobox-selectedindexchanged-event-how-to-get-the-previously-selected-index)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like this is a possible duplicate

[ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged event: how to get the previously selected index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237885/combobox-selectedindexchanged-event-how-to-get-the-previously-selected-index)

> There is nothing built in, you will need to listen for this event and keep track in a class variable.

But this answer seems to suggest a sensible way of extending the combobox to keep track of the previous index 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/425323/81053

Answer (score 0):

1-Make a List of integers
2-Bind a Button to switch to previous Screen (button Name "prevB")
3-change the ComboBox Index as Per described in the code

```
//initilize List and put current selected index in it

List<int> previousScreen = new List<int>();
previousScreen.Add(RegionComboBox.SelectedIndex);    

//Button Event
 private void prevB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (previousScreen.Count >= 2)
        {
            RegionComboBox.SelectedIndex = previousScreen[previousScreen.Count - 2];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace the ComboBox with the following control:

```
public class AdvancedComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private int myPreviouslySelectedIndex = -1;
    private int myLocalSelectedIndex = -1;

    public int PreviouslySelectedIndex { get { return myPreviouslySelectedIndex; } }

    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        myPreviouslySelectedIndex = myLocalSelectedIndex;
        myLocalSelectedIndex = SelectedIndex;
        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Now you can get the `PreviouslySelectedIndex` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use YourComboBox.Tag (or other unused string/int property) to store old selected index...

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Please note however that the original author explicitly wanted to avoid caching (unless I misunderstood your answer). It is also great if you include code snippets with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use such pair

comboBox.SelectedItem       new item

comboBox.SelectionBoxItem   old item